# fgets fails to complete reading error log - php

Tags: php, readfile

The simple thing I am trying to do below is to read a big error log file (35MB - could have been bigger :), and filter out some lines that are spamming my logs, those containing the **x-mapp** string.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$handle = @fopen("error.log", "r");
if ($handle) {
    $i=0;
    while (($line = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        if (strpos($line, 'x-mapp') !== FALSE){}
        else {
            echo $line.'<br>';
        }
        $i++;
    }

    if (!feof($handle)) {
       echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    echo $i.' proccessed';
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo 'error';
} 

echo 'finished';
```

The output I am getting is like this:

```
line-1 that doesn't contain x-mapp
line-2 that doesn't contain x-mapp
line-3 that doesn't contain x-mapp
line-4 that doesn't contain x-mapp
```

For some strange reason, the reading of the error.log file is stopped **without any error/warning**. I would except sth like this as output:

```
line-1 that doesn't contain x-mapp
line-2 that doesn't contain x-mapp
line-3 that doesn't contain x-mapp
line-4 that doesn't contain x-mapp
Many more lines not containing x-map
782933 processed
finished
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your time!

Comment: `set_time_limit(0);` http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Didn't work, same results.

Comment: Make sure your php.ini has the settings correct to allow you to open files that large.

Comment: memory_limit=1000M (Maximum amount of memory a script may consume). This should be good as well. Any other related setting?

Comment: Try registering a shutdown function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php -> $error = error_get_last();